# Android Studio Settings Activity - Will it affect the performance of my app if used a regular Activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

So I was thinking of implementing a settings activity for my android app, where I can change the background and also import a picture from photos an then use it as a background.

Should I use the template for Settings Activity for android studio, or should it be my own way? Will it have impact to the performance of the app?

I was thinking of using my own way, like just have a regular Activity page and make that my Settings page by just adding my own functions to modify my app instead of using the predefined Settings Activity. That way I can have custom buttons and interface easier.

I just want to know if using the pre-defined Settings Activity will affect my app performance-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what design you have in mind for the settings screen. The Preference Screen makes it easy to setup a settings screen similar to the Android native settings screens.

So if your goal is to create a setting similar to the native settings screen. 
Go for the PreferenceScreen.

But if you would like to have a settings screen with custom buttons or more in the style of the rest of your app.
A regular activity will do the job.